# Stripe payment gate issue while handling confirmSetupIntent in flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, subscription

I am integrating stripe payment gateway in the app for subscription flow.

Package Info:
flutter_stripe: ^9.6.0

```
paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent('10000', 'GBP');
      
      var gpay = const PaymentSheetGooglePay(merchantCountryCode: "GB",
          currencyCode: "GBP",
          testEnv: true);

      print(paymentIntent);

      //STEP 2: Initialize Payment Sheet
      await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
              allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true,
            setupIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent![
            'client_secret'], //Gotten from payment intent
              style: ThemeMode.light,
              merchantDisplayName: 'Abhi',
              googlePay: gpay))
              // paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent![
              // 'client_secret'], //Gotten from payment intent
              // style: ThemeMode.light,
              // merchantDisplayName: 'Abhi',
              // googlePay: gpay))
          .then((value) {
            print(value);

      });

//STEP 3: Display Payment sheet

 await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();

// I have open payment sheet for collecting details now i want response  SetupPaymentSheet how can I handle that.

await Stripe.instance.confirmSetupIntent(
      paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent!['client_secret'],
      params: const PaymentMethodParams.card(paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData()),
    ).then((value) {
      if(kDebugMode) print("Payment Successfully");
      if(kDebugMode) print(value);
    });
```

In step three PaymentMethodParams parameter is required. while passing the above value :  Card details not complete, message: Card details not complete, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null)) I am getting above error.

I want setup the card for subscription. PaymentMethodParams required card details, I don’t understand why confirmSetupIntent setup needs card details before open the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The `Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet()` method is used to display the payment sheet.  You're using `confirmSetupIntent()`, which is used to confirm the Setup Intent *after* payment details have been collected.  That method is not used to show the payment sheet.

Have a look at [the Flutter Stripe documentation](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/cce4c83b57b98be79db24e7b2efc05c5cd75e2cf/docs/sheet.mdx#L125-L128) for more details (GitHub source link as their website seems to be down at the moment).

Comment: I want payment details for the subscription. That is why I am opening SetupPaymentSheetParameters and I need to handle response for subscription 
 using confirmSetupIntent.

Comment: You need to present the payment sheet after initializing it, then the payment details will be provided, then you can proceed with confirming the Setup Intent or whatever else you want to do.  Right now your code is initializing the payment sheet but isn't presenting it.

Comment: I am able to open a payment sheet and store data using Step Intent. Now I want to handle the response. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question?  What response do you want to handle? How do you want to handle it?  What have you tried that hasn't worked?